# Métodos abstratos não obrigam a implementação

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Estou fazendo um trabalho e implementei um método abstrato, o caso faço uma classe herdar dessa, mas o compilador não acusa erro pela falta de implementação dos métodos. Eu estou fazendo errado?

```
class online{
    private:
    public:
        online();
        virtual void build() = 0;
};

class F : public online{
    public:
        F();
};
```

Eu gostaria que a classe `F` fosse obrigada a implementar o método `build`.

Comment: Eu acho que dessa forma aí F acaba sendo uma classe abstrata não? Tenta instanciar um objeto dela. Acredito que  forma de "obrigar" alguém a implementar o método é na hora de tentar instanciar a classe.

Comment: Está tendo alguma dificuldade? Tentou fazer e algo diferente do que espera ocorreu? Diga o que precisa e que não está sendo o que quer. https://ideone.com/dKoYpc

Comment: Sim, quando eu criei o objeto o compilador acusou erro. Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 1):

A sua premissa está **errada**. Em C++ não há como "forçar" a implementação de um método (virtual ou puramente virtual) em uma determinada classe na cadeia de heranças.

A única regra é que todas as funções virtuais devem ter uma implementação para que essa classe possa ser *instanciável*, ou seja, o erro em tempo de compilação que você está esperando só poderia acontecer caso haja a tentativa de instanciar essa classe derivada.

Veja só:

```
class online{
    public:
        virtual void build() = 0;
};

class F : public online{
    public:
        F();
};

int main( void )
{
    F f();  /* Tentando instanciar a classe derivada */
    return 0;
}
```

Erro de compilação:

```
online.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
online.cpp:14:4: error: invalid abstract return type for function ‘F f()’
  F f();
    ^
online.cpp:6:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘F’:
 class F : public online{
       ^
online.cpp:3:22: note:  virtual void online::build()
         virtual void build() = 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

Marque a função que vai sobreescrever com override, isso fará o compilador acusar erro quando tentar instanciar a classe abstrata.
Você deve usar um destrutor virtual também.
Tente habilitar os warnings do compilador também para ver se realmente não aparece nada.

```
class Online {    
public:
    Online() = default;
    virtual ~Online(){}
    virtual void build() = 0;
};

class Foo : public Online{
    public:
        Foo();
        void build() override;
};
```